# Adding a paths to Laravel 4.1 paths.php

Tags: laravel-4

Laravel 4.1 has a file `paths.php` and it has some paths: app, public, base and storage.
I wish to add another path so what I did:

I wrote this in paths.php

```
  'upload' => __DIR__.'/../some/path/uploads',
```

Then I copied and pasted and edited this in `helpers.php`

```
if ( ! function_exists('upload_path'))
{
    function upload_path($path = '')
    {
        return app()->make('path.upload').($path ? '/'.$path : $;
    }
}
```

But after a few days it disappeared!
I am wondering if I did it wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "disappeared"?

Comment: Thanks @Andreas, the code above that I added to helpers.php disappeared. I tested with it a couple of days ago and after a couple of days it was removed. I am wondering if there is any inherit behavior perhaps in Composer that may have overwritten the `helpers.php` file. I am asking if I needed to make the changes somewhere else or perhaps I shouldn't have made these changes? I was puzzled by losing the changes and was looking for an explanation.

Comment: Are you editing helpers.php inside the vendor directory?

Comment: Yup. I went to where these functions were declared. I am new to Laravel. Where am I supposed to copy/edit the helpers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Best" way I found to handle this were the included configuration folders.

Inside `root/app/config/` you can add a host specific folder (there is one called `local` by default).
You can add `someFolderName` and then inside `root/bootstrap/start.php` update this array:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

    'local' => array('outLocalHostsName'),
    'someFolderName' => array('SomeOtherMachinesHostname'),
));
```

Now go back to the folder and create an `app.php` file inside it (remember `root/app/config/someFolderName/app.php`) and add some value in it like so:

```
'someKeyNameHere' => 'some path string here'
```

Now you can access it anywhere using:

```
Config::get('app.someKeyNameHere')
```

This seems to work great for me.

Answer (score 0):

Never edit files in the vendor directory, it and its contents is entirely managed by Composer, and its contents will be overwritten when doing `composer update`.

If you want to add your own custom functions, autoload them in your composer.json using the "files" autoload rule.

```
"autoload": {
  "files": ["app/helpers.php"]
}
```

Comment: would that override the file in the vendor directory? Do I need to copy the contents of the original file into the new file?